# How to values from iframe send to div element?

Tags: javascript, php, database, iframe, text-editor

Today I did a my text editor in iframe. I know that values from iframe doesn't send to database. My first idea relies on sending the values from iframe to the `div`, and that `div` data send to DataBase with the respective text formats.

```js
function wlaczTrybEdycji(){
    edytorTextowy.document.designMode = "On";
}
function execCmd(command){
    edytorTextowy.document.execCommand(command, false, null);
}
function przeniesDane(){
    var ramka = document.getElementById("ramka");
    var dodiv = document.getElementById("daneIframe");
    dodiv == ramka;
}
```

```css
.textarea2{
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    height: 240px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
<body onload="wlaczTrybEdycji();">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="EdytorTextowy">
        <div class="przyciskiTextEdytor">
            <button onclick="execCmd('bold');">BOLD</button>
        </div>     
        <iframe name="edytorTextowy" class="textarea2" id="ramka"></iframe>
          <div id="daneIframe">
          
          </div>
        <button type="submit" name="wyslijText">WYSLIJ</button><!-- here send from "daneIframe" to DB (PHP)-->
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What you want us to do ? difficult to understand from your question

Comment: Unfortunelly I can't send data's from iframe to data base.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to understand about what you're doing is that the browser has rules about Cross-document communication.

> A page inside an **iframe** is not allowed to access or modify the DOM of its parent and vice-versa unless both have the same **origin**. So putting it in a different way: document or script loaded from one origin is prevented from getting or setting properties of a document from another **origin**.

Here's the [docs on Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) from MDN.

If the iframe and the page that loads it are of the same origin you should be able to do exactly what you're trying to do just fine. If not, then these documents need to be made available in the same origin to do so.

Comment: I use XAMPP in this moment. Is it because of him?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I understand now! You can get elements with ajax or javascript like so :

**JavaScript for the Example**

The JavaScript displayed here is just an example to show how to access to iframe elements.

```
// attach handlers once iframe is loaded
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {

    // get reference to form to attach button onclick handlers
    var form = document.getElementById('demoForm');

    // set height of iframe and display value
    form.elements.button1.onclick = function() {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm');
        var ht = ifrm.style.height = '160px';
        this.form.elements.display.value = 'The iframe\'s height is: ' + ht;
    }

    // increment and display counter variable contained in iframed document
    form.elements['button2'].onclick = function() {
        // get reference to iframe window
        var win = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow;
        var counter = ++win.counter; //  increment
        this.form.elements['display'].value = 'counter in iframe is: ' + counter;
    }

    // reference form element in iframed document
    form.elements.button3.onclick = function() {
        var re = /[^-a-zA-Z!,'?\s]/g; // to filter out unwanted characters
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm');
        // reference to document in iframe
        var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
        // get reference to greeting text box in iframed document
        var fld = doc.forms['iframeDemoForm'].elements['greeting'];
        var val = fld.value.replace(re, '');
        // display value in text box
        this.form.elements.display.value = 'The greeting is: ' + val;
    }

    form.elements.button4.onclick = function() {
        // get reference to iframe window
        var win = document.getElementById('ifrm').contentWindow;
        win.clearGreeting(); // call function in iframed document
    }
}
```

> Or you can do something like this in jquery :

```
    var content=$("iframe").contents().find('body').html();
   //alert elements in iframe or show elements as a response in and div                                                             
    alert(content);
```